# How to embed excel files in onedrive for business

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, office365api

One drive business is not supporting embedding excel files. but i have a strong requirement to do so.  in [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Embed-your-Excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-SharePoint-or-OneDrive-for-Business-7af74ce6-e8a0-48ac-ba3b-a1dd627b7773) example they explain how to do it manually using the classic one drive interface.  is there anyway i can do it through coding ?

graph client snippets this is the line to get a share link

```
Permission permission = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[id].CreateLink("view", "organization").Request().PostAsync();
```

but only view and edit is available. i tried adding  " &action=embedview"  to the url end but it also not working.  anyone have any idea how to achive this ?

and also how to generate the preview link from this

```
Permission permission = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[id].Preview("",100).Request().PostAsync();
```

this says cannot convert item preview info to permission.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The **&action=embedview** is not supported by the Graph. The following pic show the suppoted value.

[image]

**Note**: Not all Graph API can be access by the **Graph Client Library**.

> this says cannot convert item preview info to permission.

For this, you need to use such **Preview preview** but not the **Permission permission**. They are not the same type. On my side, I don't have the Preview method, so we maybe not use the same version Graph Client Library.

Comment: Thanks a lot Seiya Su . could you please tell me where did you get the relevant documentation for the graph client library for asp.net?   because i didnt find any documentation regarding the client library fuctions and methods. Except for graph documentation and sample coding snippets .

Comment: Just see the source code of Graph Client Library in the Github